# Python - why is += operator not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and was working on a simple password cracker for practice with lists and dictionaries.  Half way thru my test program I ran into this error.

```
PS E:\python_projects> python test.py
  File "test.py", line 9
    global counter += 1
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code...

```
maxChar = 4
counter = 0
alph = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
passCheck = []
password = 'f'
password = str(password.lower())

def loopTest():
    global counter += 1

    if counter <= maxChar:
        loopTest()  #Nests loops

    else:
        for letter in alph:     #scans letters
            passCheck[0] = letter

            if passCheck == password:   #checks password
                print 'found password: ' + passCheck

            else:
                print passCheck

loopTest()

print 'Debug.'
print counter
```

there may be other errors and that's fine but I don't understand why I'm getting hung up on a += that I thought I understood, anyway thanks for looking!

Comment: That's not how you use `global`.

Comment: That's a syntax error. I'd take a look at how `global` is supposed to be used, and see why you're not able to do anything but making declarations or whatever

Comment: Best idea: get rid of `global` and use parameters and a return value.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed two different ideas in Python, a ["`global` statement"](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) and an ["augmented assignment statement."](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)

A "`global` statement" has a very simple syntax:

```
"global" identifier ("," identifier)*
```

No expression is allowed in a `global` statement.

Perhaps you wanted to say:

```
global counter
counter += 1
```

Comment: Ahh great ok let me give that a try thank you!